# Linux screen command, auto renamed on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, gnu-screen

I use screen to login multi terminal.

The best way I use screen is that I can name(control + a + A ) a screen to tell which machine I am logging.

But on CentOS 7, the name I typed was auto changed to the command I just type.

Such as I was logging a MySQL machine, I rename the screen to 'mysql' to show me it is a mysql I was using. But when I type 'ls /data', the screen name auto change to 'ls /data', what I want is no matter I type, it always show 'mysql'.

Comment: does my answer solute your problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can always escape to the normal editing mode with screen by:

```
Ctl+A+ESC
```

Comment: What do you mean? I just want the name I type keep itself.